# C++ Simple Multicolumn File Read

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, file-io

I am trying to read a file with multiple columns to output all results with an income of over $100,000 and a GPA of less than or equal to 2.3.  I'm not able to figure out which approach is correct.  The file output does not even appear on the terminal.  Please let me know if more specifics are needed.  Here is the [FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/30ulzlrj7ryv699/Students.txt).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

ifstream inputFile;
char *student = new char[];
int salary=100000,
    grades=2.3;

inputFile.open("Students.txt");

if(inputFile.fail()==1)
    {
    cout<<"File opening failed";
    }
    else
        {
            while(!inputFile.eof())
            {
                inputFile>>student;
            }

            inputFile.close();
        }

int income=student[0];
int gpa=student[0];


    for(int i=0;i!=inputFile.eof();i++)
    {
        income=student[i];
        gpa=student[i];

        if(income>=salary && gpa<=grades)
        {
            cout<<" "<<income<<" "<<gpa<<endl;
        }
    }


cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: First, `char *student = new char[];` does not make sense--you need to specify a size in the brackets.

Comment: Well, he was president from.... j/k


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723224/using-sscanf-to-parse-a-string

Comment: What do  you think this does? `for(int i=0;i!=inputFile.eof();i++)
`?  Hint: it is nonsensical (but will compile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const int MAX_STUDENTS = 100;

int main()
{
int numberOfStudents = 0;

//Instantiate read file object
std::ifstream inputFile("Student.txt");

//Instantiate an array of income
int income[MAX_STUDENTS];
float gpa[MAX_STUDENTS];

//Check if the file is open
if(inputFile.fail() == 1)
    std::cout << "\nFile opening failed!\n";
else
{
    while(!inputFile.eof())
    {
        //Read file into class
        inputFile >> income[numberOfStudents];
        inputFile >> gpa[numberOfStudents];

        //^^**In whatever order your data members are in**

        //Check if gpa and income meet requirements
        if(income[numberOfStudents] > 100000 && gpa[numberOfStudents] <= 2.3)
        {
            /*Output student if gpa is less than or equal to 2.3 AND 
            greater than 100000*/
            std::cout << "\nStudent #: " << numberOfStudents + 1 << ' ' << std::endl;
            std::cout << income[numberOfStudents] << ' ';
            std::cout << gpa[numberOfStudents]    << ' ';
            std::cout << ' ' << std::endl;
        }
        //Increase number of students
        numberOfStudents++;
    }
    //Close file
    inputFile.close();
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Isn't there a more direct way of doing this without classes?  I continue to get class type errors.

Comment: You could do it with structs.  What errors are you getting?  You need to modify the code to make sure it reads in the text file correctly.

Comment: Now I am getting identifier is undefined and >> no operator matches these operands.

Comment: The file reads everything but outputs only memory addresses then crashes.

Comment: Copy and paste the updated code again.  Works on my computer.

Comment: Tried it, but the memory location's only display, not the actual data.

Comment: Erase EVERYTHING in your code.  Ctrl + a, then Ctrl + c my code.  Move in text file I supplied you with.  Run code.

Comment: I've done that, no luck.  Where do you suggest I put this text file?

Comment: Make a screenshot of your code, output and textfile.  Everything works on this end.  What IDE are you using??

Comment: yes, it did what was asked alright.  I wish it'd go through the entire original file though.

Comment: @Klinetel You can write it to go through the entire original file.

Comment: How would you recommend me going about this?